# React date picker - Carpool app - State management

Tags: reactjs, date, state, picker

I'm trying to make a simple booking app for carpooling with colleagues. I am using MERN stack and React Date Picker.

I have 4 empty seats available per day, in my car.

How can I manage the state of each day and update the available seats when a user books a ride? Creating a document in the database for each date doesn't look like a good approach.

Is this something that can be done with Redux?

Answer (score 1):

- first you need to decide which hours your car service starts. starting and ending time. When user books your car, user should see the select options. (maybe from 5am till 10pm). If each day has a different schedule, you need to write a logic to display those start time and end time properly
- you should also determine the time interval. 15 or 30 minutes intervals. (User can pick 8.15, 8.30,8.45,9) because when you show the options to the user in select element, you cannot show options for each minute. that way it will be easier to track booking period.
- I think you should create only booking document. Because you do not have multiple cars.

  ```
  id
  number_of_people
  booking_time
  booker_info (email,phone,name,etc)
  ```